# Windows Phone 7 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, sdk

I just installed VS 2010 Professional Edition, then the Service Pack 1. So now I wanted to install the 7.1 RC for WP7. The first thing it tries to do is download VS 2010 Express. Is this normal? Do I really have to install 2 versions of VS to develop for WP7?

Comment: does it really want to download/install it? I really don't remember that well (might be it downloaded VSExpress) but it did not install the express version on my machine - same config you mentioned.

Comment: It wants to DL it, and I've had bad experiences with multiple VSs on my machine so I stopped it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a valid and applicable edition of Visual Studio 2010 installed, then the installer installs the SDK, Expression Blend, emulator, etc. and adds the necessary project templates into your existing edition. It will not install Visual Studio 2010 Express if you have already have an existing edition, so there are no issues around multiple installs of Visual Studio.

Comment: So it downloads VS Express but doesn't install it?

Comment: If you do the web install, I wouldn't expect it to download VS Express, though it may do.

Comment: Ok it downloads it but doesn't install.